# Android custom independent push notifications

Tags: android, push-notification

How can I implement push notifications on Android without using Firebase cloud messaging and Google play services. I would use MQTT, but I don't know how would I handle it on Android client. Background services are very restricted since Oreo, and I see no way of keeping reliable connection to MQTT broker when app is in background.

I was thinking AlarmManager and starting scheduled jobs to check for new messages, but Android seems to ignore that while in "Doze" mode.

I could have foreground service running constantly but that just seems wrong.

Maximum tolerable latency between sending and receiving notification is 20-30 seconds.

There are some 3rd party services that offer push notifications, how are they doing it?

I need to be independent of FCM because Google is blocked in China, and that's my use case.

Comment: your question is ambiguous

Comment: for china you can use something like baidu

Comment: Pushy (https://pushy.me/) is an MQTT push notification service that also works in China. Full disclosure - I founded Pushy.